# Highcharts stacked chart with spline independent from x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating a chart for showing some data. On the x axis I got some items, and for each Item I got a stacked bar chart. In my example I call them item 1 till item 5. Following is the code I got so far:

```
xAxis: {
          categories: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5']
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal'
          }
      },
      series: [{
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Item 1 of stacked bar charts',
          data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
      }, {
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Item 2 of stacked bar charts',
          data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
      }, {
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Item 3 of stacked bar charts',
          data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 2]
      },
```

Now I want to add a spline, representing live data. For every second I want to plot a new datapoint on this spline. Since I only have 5 items on the x axis, its not possible to just add the spline the ordinairy way.

Is it possible to have a spline running independant from the x axis? Or maybe theres another solution?

UPDATE:

I was not clear on what I want. Like in the example, I got 5 different categories on the x axis. The x axis is time based. What I want:

I got an x axis representing 60 minutes. I got 5 items, 4 of 10 minutes and 1 of 20 minutes. Every item has its own stacked bar chart. The width of every item should represent the percentage in time of the x axis. So 20 minutes of 60 means 33%.

What I also want, is that I can plot a spline on every second of the 60 minute x axis. In the example of 60 minutes, it means I got to insert 3600 values into the spline. It is live data, so when I start I got 0 values and when 30 minutes psast I got 1800 values.

I hope it is clear what I want.

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific about what you want. Anything you plot must have an x axis position, so no - it can't be independent of the x axis. But I assume you mean something other than what you've said :)

Comment: Do you want something similar to this chart? http://jsfiddle.net/g8w6ffbq/2/